# XslCompiledTransform.Transform 64 bit Memory issues

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, 32bit-64bit, xslcompiledtransform

Our application uses the XslCompiledTransform.Transform function. The behavior is normal if we run it in 32 bit mode, however when running under 64 bit mode, the memory consumption just jumps way too high (and eventually throws out of memory exception). Same code, same machine - one works while the other does not ....Has anyone seen a similar issue and have a workaround?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Is it actually an `OutOfMemoryException` or a `StackOverflowException` due to insufficient memory being allocated to the thread? I ask because I ran into this type of problem on an x64 web server running IIS, as [it only allocates 256kb to a Thread's stack by default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/31/stack-sizes-in-iis-affects-asp-net.aspx). I had to do some of the larger transforms ([like DocBook to XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook_XSL)) in a Thread with more room for the stack in this fashion:

```cs
var stackedThread = new Thread(RunXsltWithMoreMemory, 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var threadParameters = ThreadXsltParameters {
    InputStream = inputStream;    // Source XML
    OutputStream = outputStream;  // Resultant XML
};
stackedThread.Start(threadParameters);
stackedThread.Join();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run into this problem and have resolved it by compiling my XSLTs using the xsltc command-line utility.

```
 xsltc someXsl.xsl /settings:DTD+,document+,script-
```

The xsltc command-line utility is documented here on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399405.aspx.

And then once you've run the command-line utility, an assembly is generated which you use in your code like this:

```
 xmlTransform.Load(Assembly.Load(assemblyName).GetType(assemblyName));
```

It also seems to have significantly increased performance of the transformations.

Answer (score 1):

While XslCompiledTransform is ancient technology at this point and might not be used much, I've done some recent testing in .NET 4.5 and it seems like this memory consumption bug has been fixed.

I haven't been able to find any definitive indication from Microsoft (I can't seem to access the old Connect bug anymore), but testing with a fairly complex XSLT (several thousand lines) with plenty of xpath expressions does not show any abnormal memory usage in 64-bit processes in .NET 4.5. Executing this same XSLT in .NET 3.5 64-bit immediately jumps to 6.5 GB on an 8 GB machine and keeps going up from there.

I'm curious as to whether or not anyone else can still reproduce the bad memory usage behaviour with XslCompiledTransform in 64-bit .NET 4.5 or knows of any updates from Microsoft related this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Known bug - See this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/508748